# Background size property messing my header

Tags: css, background-image

I have a 600px tall header which uses backround image as its bg. When the screen is over 1600px, I use cover and the default is contain. Overlaying the header is one image(absolutely positioned) that is 500px tall.

When I resize the browser, the header doesn't keep its height, which can easily be seen by the overlaying image overlapping the header.

Here is the code:

```
/* ===== HEADER ==== */

header{
height: 600px;
min-height:600px;
width:100%;
min-width:100%;
background-image: url(../images/headerBG.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;

}
#bgOverlay{
position: absolute;
top: 60px;
left: 30%;
}

/* ==== MEDIA QUERIES   ==== */
@media only screen and (min-width:1600px){
header{background-size: cover;}
}
```

And the link to see it: http://www.madebym.net/test/crazysunsets/index.html

Comment: What if you put `background-size: 1600px 600px`? It keeps the height and width of you background (not sure this is what you want to do)

Comment: I want my header to always be 600px tall, and the bg-image to scale with cover and contain.

Comment: So your background picture won't keep the proportions right?

Comment: I thought that was handled with cover or contain. I am missing something trivial here.

Comment: How exactly do you want this background picture to be displayed? You want it to be 600px tall but what about the width? Do you want to keep the picture proportions?

Comment: Yeah, 600px tall, width is always 100%, keeping the aspect ratio, of course.

Comment: So what about applying `background-size: auto 600px`? Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve my problem, one needs to apply: background-size: 100% 600px;

This way the header is always 600px tall, and the image keeps its aspect ratio.